# Paginado en grocery crud no funciona bien

Tags: php

el problema que tengo es con el paginado de grocery crud aparentemente si me lo esta haciendo bien pero el problema en especifico que tengo es que por ejemplo estoy en la página 20, edito un producto y cuando guardo los datos en vez de quedarseme en la página 20 me retorna a la primera página y eso es muy incomodo.
De que forma podria resolverse este problema para que guarde el estado de la página en que esta???

Answer (score 1):

captura la página actual en un `hidden field` y envíala al servidor mediante el `POST` al editar, cuando se termine de guardar, pregunta si esa variable tiene dato y si es numérico, lo redireccionas a la página donde se quedó.